# Is it possible to control chromecast from an google-home-fulfillment?

Tags: actions-on-google

I would like to develop an own google-action for google-home.

When I write a [google-home-fulfillment](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/fulfillment) will I be able to control my google chromecast?

How would I authenticate myself against a google chromecast?

Comment: Currently there are no APIs to access Chromecast devices.

Comment: Is there another possibility / SDK which would allow to control chromecast via google home?

Comment: Not at the moment